# added labels to a pandas df and then concatenated that df to another df - now the labels are a list - what gives?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two csv files that I need to concatenate. I read in the two csv files as pandas dfs. One has col labels and the other doesn't. I add labels to the df that needed them, then concatenated the two dfs. Concatenation works fine, but the labels I added look like individual lists or something. I can't figure out what python is doing, especially when you print the labels and the df and it all looks good. Call this approach one.

I was able to fix the problem by adding col labels to the csv when I read it in. Then it works fine. Call this approach two. What is going on with approach one?

Code and results below.

**Approach One**

```
#read in the vectors as a pandas df vec
vecs=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,filename), header=None)

#label the feature vectors v1-vn and attach to the df
endrange=features+1
string='v'
vecnames=[string + str(i) for i in range(1,endrange)]
vecs.columns = [vecnames]
print('\nvecnames')
display(vecnames)  #they look ok here
display(vecs.head()) #they look ok here

#read in the IDs and phrases as a pandas df
recipes=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,'2a_2d_id_all_recipe_forms.csv'))
print('\nrecipes file - ids and recipe phrases')
display(recipes.head())

test=pd.concat([recipes, vecs], axis=1)
print('\ncol labels for vectors look like lists!')
display(test.head())
```

*Results of Approach One*:

```
 ['v1',
 'v2',
 'v3',
 'v4',
 'v5',
 'v6',
 'v7',
 'v8',
 'v9',
 'v10',
 'v11',
 'v12',
 'v13',
 'v14',
 'v15',
 'v16',
 'v17',
 'v18',
 'v19',
 'v20',
 'v21',
 'v22',
 'v23',
 'v24',
 'v25']
```

[image]

**Approach Two**

By adding the col labels to the csv when I read in the unlabeled file, it works fine. Why?

```
#label the feature vectors v1-vn and attach to the df
endrange=features+1
string='v'
vecnames=[string + str(i) for i in range(1,endrange)]

#read in the vectors as a pandas df and label the cols
vecs=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,filename), names=vecnames, header=None)

#read in the IDs and phrases as a pandas df
recipes=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,'2a_2d_id_all_recipe_forms.csv'))

test=pd.concat([recipes, vecs], axis=1)
print('\ncol labels for vectors as expected')
display(test.head())
```

*Results of Approach Two*

[image]

Comment: it's hard to diagnose or reproduce this behavior when the code relies on interacting with files that exist only on your system. Can you hard-code some example dataframes that reproduce the issue?

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: ok. criticisms accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odd behaviour comes from this line:

```
vecs.columns = [vecnames]
```

`vecnames` is *already* a list, but the above line wraps it in another list. The column names display properly when you print the DataFrame, but concatenating `vecs` with another DataFrame causes pandas to unwrap the column names of `vecs` into single-element tuples.

**Fix:** change the above line to:

```
vecs.columns = vecnames
```

And run everything else as is.

Comment: This is really interesting and helps gives insight into the beauty of python. I really appreciate your taking the time to answer.